# Install problem of ubuntu 20.04 on Lenovo slim5 14-ITL

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, 20.04, lenovo, ideapad

Laptop spec:

|  | Details |
| --- | --- |
| Name | Lenovo Ideapad Slim5 14-ITL 5D M16 |
| CPU | Intel i5-1135G7 (Tigerlake, 11th) |
| GPU | NVIDIA Geforce MX450 2GB |
| RAM | 16GB DDR4 3200MHz |

I want to install Ubuntu on my new laptop, Lenovo Ideapad Slim5 14-ITL.
After installation of Ubuntu 20.04, however, only the following error message appeared, and Ubuntu didn't turn on.

[image: Image of error message]

```
[ 4.001152] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send Intel_Write_DDC (-22)
[64.610552] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: no reply expected, received 0x0
[64.714001] skl_hd_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: failed to init link iDisp1: -517
```

I cannot search about my problem exactly, so I write this question.

Can you do me a favor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

**This seems to work:**

- First, boot Ubuntu in recovery mode.

  > With BIOS, quickly press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up the GNU GRUB menu. (If you see the Ubuntu logo, you've missed the point where you can enter the GRUB menu.) With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the Escape key to get grub menu.
  > [source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)
- Then, open a terminal and run:

  ```
  cd /etc/default
  ```
- Next, edit the `grub` file with `sudo`, i.e.:

  ```
  sudo vi grub
  ```

  or

  ```
  sudo pluma grub
  ```
- Look for the line:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="..."
  ```

  and change it to:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
  ```
- Save the file.
- Then in terminal run:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```

After that, I could boot Ubuntu normally.